# Excel to XML encoding problems with French words

Tags: xml, excel, vba, encoding, french

I already found partial solution here for my problem with encoding with some French words...

However! Few characters are doing problems and I cant figure out why. I have tried to do separate VBA script for directly copying this problematic word with those characters and it was OK, which is real mystery to me!

With my complex translation code ([see old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42070177/excel-data-to-xml-makes-wrong-characters-with-french-words)), in excel sheet I have **Français** and in XML then wrong representation **FranÃ§ais**

**CODE which works OK**

```
Sub EncodingRepair()

Dim strLine As String
Dim strPath As String

Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim strFolderPath As String

strFolderPath = "C:\Users\zema\Documents\"

Set fOutputFile = fso.CreateTextFile(strFolderPath & "EncodingRepair.xml", True)

strLine = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("wording").Range("G16").Text

fOutputFile.WriteLine (strLine & vbCrLn)

End Sub
```

Only difference here is loading string... In this small code I am loading Text from direct Cell (just for try) and in my complex code, there is loading from **.Range** object where I put finded **.Row**

**Complex CODE where I have problems with last few words**

```
If intChoice <> 0 Then

strPath = Application.FileDialog( _
msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)

Dim strFolderPath As String

strFolderPath = Left(strPath, Len(strPath) - 4)
Set fGermanOutputFile = fso.CreateTextFile((strFolderPath & "_German.xml"), True, True)
Set fItalianOutputFile = fso.CreateTextFile((strFolderPath & "_Italian.xml"), True, True)
Set fFrenchOutputFile = fso.CreateTextFile((strFolderPath & "_French.xml"), True, True)

Open strPath For Input As #1

AlarmString = "RESETNoTranslation"

Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, strLine

    AllLine = strLine

    Alarm = InStr(1, strLine, AlarmString)

    intLastFoundChar = 0

    strGermanLine = ""
    strFrenchLine = ""
    strItalianLine = ""

    For intI = 0 To (UBound(ArrStrOpeningTags, 1) - 1)

        intFoundString = InStr(strLine, ArrStrOpeningTags(intI))

        If intFoundString <> 0 Then
            intI = 4
        End If

    Next intI

    If ((intFoundString <> 0) And (Alarm = 0)) Then

        For intJ = 0 To (UBound(ArrStrParamsToReplace) - 1)


            strLine = Right(strLine, Len(strLine) - intLastFoundChar)

            strStringToLookFor = (ArrStrParamsToReplace(intJ) & "=""")

            intFoundString = InStr(1, strLine, strStringToLookFor, vbBinaryCompare)

            If intFoundString <> 0 Then
                intStringSplitIndex = (intFoundString + Len(strStringToLookFor))

                strStringToLookFor = Right(strLine, Len(strLine) - intStringSplitIndex + 1)

                strDummyString = Left(strLine, intStringSplitIndex - 1)
                strGermanLine = strGermanLine & strDummyString
                strFrenchLine = strFrenchLine & strDummyString
                strItalianLine = strItalianLine & strDummyString

                intLastFoundChar = intLastFoundChar + intStringSplitIndex

                intFoundString = InStr(strStringToLookFor, """")

                If intFoundString <> 0  strStringToLookFor = Left(strStringToLookFor, intFoundString - 1)

                    Set rngFoundString = rngEnglishDictionary.Find(strStringToLookFor)


                    If (rngFoundString Is Nothing) Then
                        Debug.Print "String " & strStringToLookFor & " not found!"

                        strGermanLine = strGermanLine & strStringToLookFor & """"
                        strFrenchLine = strFrenchLine & strStringToLookFor & """"
                        strItalianLine = strItalianLine & strStringToLookFor & """"
                    Else

                        intWordToReplaceIndex = rngEnglishDictionary.Find(strStringToLookFor).Row - rngEnglishDictionary.Row + 1


                        strGermanLine = strGermanLine & rngGermanDictionary(intWordToReplaceIndex) & """"
                        strFrenchLine = strFrenchLine & rngFrenchDictionary(intWordToReplaceIndex) & """"
                        strItalianLine = strItalianLine & rngItalianDictionary(intWordToReplaceIndex) & """"
                    End If

                    intLastFoundChar = intLastFoundChar + Len(strStringToLookFor)

                End If
            End If

        Next intJ

        If intJ = 2 Then
            strEndOfLine = Right(AllLine, Len(AllLine) - intLastFoundChar)
            strGermanLine = strGermanLine & strEndOfLine
            strFrenchLine = strFrenchLine & strEndOfLine
            strItalianLine = strItalianLine & strEndOfLine
        End If

    Else

    strGermanLine = strLine
    strFrenchLine = strLine
    strItalianLine = strLine

    End If

    fGermanOutputFile.WriteLine (strGermanLine & vbCrLn)
    fFrenchOutputFile.WriteLine (strFrenchLine & vbCrLn)
    fItalianOutputFile.WriteLine (strItalianLine & vbCrLn)

    strGermanLine = ""
    strFrenchLine = ""
    strItalianLine = ""

Loop

End If   
End Sub
```

Comment: Can't see no Unicode enforcing in the linked example; and that is exactly what  you need to do: set the `TriState` property to true: `Set fOutputFile = fso.CreateTextFile(strFolderPath & "EncodingRepair.xml", True)`

Comment: Ah, sorry, my mistake... I tried it without it. But it worked anyway. It just dont work in my complex code. (EDITED)

Comment: Please post the code that causes the error. I cannot reproduce your problem with this code.

Comment: See the old post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42070177/excel-data-to-xml-makes-wrong-characters-with-french-words

Comment: First of all: don't create a thread for a problem with code in another thread. Post your troublesome code _here_. Second: like I said: _you do not have the `, True` option set in your `CreateTextFile` lines. Please do as you recommend yourself: specify to write as unicode. Then post back _here_ with the troublesome code, not some snippet that actually works.

Comment: I edited this thread. Sorry for troubles.

Comment: `Open strPath For Input As #1` <= There is your problem. It is not the writing but the reading. Use a `TextStream`with proper encoding for reading too, not the built in "`Open`. Also `vbCrLn` does not exists, it's `vbCrLf` instead.

Comment: Thank you, sir. I am very grateful.

Comment: Ignore the `TextStream` in my comment, it will not work. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input file is not Unicode but utf-8, so the `fso TextStream` approach will not work for reading, as the FileSystemObject knows only ASCII and Unicode, not Utf-8. For the latter you need a reference to Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects and an ADODB.Stream.

Here an example that you can build around your code which uses UTF-8 as input encoding and writes Unicode to the "EncodingRepair.xml" file:

```
Sub EncodingRepair()

Dim strPath As String

Dim fso As Object, inFile As Object
Dim fOutputFile As Object, AllLine As String
Dim LineArray As Variant
Dim strFolderPath As String

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set inFile = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")

strFolderPath = "C:\Users\zema\Documents\"
strPath = "C:\00_Tools\test\test.txt"

Set fOutputFile = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\00_Tools\test\EncodingRepair.xml", True, True)

Set inFile = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
inFile.Charset = "utf-8"
inFile.Open
inFile.LoadFromFile (strPath)

AlarmString = "RESETNoTranslation"

While Not inFile.EOS
    alltext = inFile.ReadText
    LineArray = Split(alltext, vbCrLf)
    For i = 0 To UBound(LineArray)
        AllLine = LineArray(i)
        'do your magic
        fOutputFile.WriteLine AllLine
    Next i
Wend

End Sub
```

Make sure to always use the proper encoding both when reading and writing.

Comment: Dim fso As FileSystemObject, inFile As ADODB.Stream
Dim fOutputFile As TextStream, AllLine As String Does not work for me, as it writes me User-defined type not defined. It does not even lights blue as VBA cant recognize this type.

Comment: Sorry, I usually add the required references and use early binding. i have changed the code to use late binding instead. Should work for you now.

Comment: I actually added some libraries in references and it works fine... Now I just to use it in correct way in my whole script. Thank you again for help.

Comment: Note: In many Microsoft libraries, "Unicode" means UTF-16. Unicode is a character set with several encoding, including UTF-16 and UTF-8.